# Stopping windows from moving and resizing after switching users

Tags: windows-10

I would like some help with this. Every time we switch users in Windows 10, all non-maximized windows get resized and moved towards the top left corner. We use only one 32" display (3840x2160), and scaling is set to 100% on both accounts.

Things I've tried already:

1. Shown hidden devices on Device Manager and deleted all past devices. Now the only thing there is the active display.
2. In Registry Editor, removed all entries but the actual display in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\ScaleFactors`
3. Since 2 didn't work, restored to previous settings, deleted all non-simulated or actual devices and set every relevant setting (primsize, actsize, scaling, etc.) to the same settings of my active display.

Locking the computer and letting the display go to sleep does not alter windows size or placement. Only switching users does.

​Does anybody know what else can I try?

Comment: What happens is that the display is not connected in windows to that account anymore, and therefor the resolution is set to a standard one, such as 1280x1024. You can try minimizing all windows before switching, and restore them after. Sometimes that will allow you to get around this problem. But its a known issue that many people face. It is partly due to the connection type you use, which is either Display Port or HDMI, which all are "smart" connectors that install and uninstall upon turning off the monitor etc. DVI and SUB-D (vga) should not have this issue, but don't support 4k.

Comment: But if that were the case, then I would have the same issue simply by pressing WIN+L and then logging back in. But doing that preserves the windows size and position.